# unable to free up space on samsung s3 mini

Tags: insufficient-memory, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I've got a Samsung S3 mini. It keeps telling me that I have insufficient space. I have just deleted loads of photos and videos, I only have a few apps. Instagram, pinterest, watsapp and picsart. I deleted two of the apps but it's still saying insufficiant space. I have no idea what i'm doing wrong? I have restarted the phone to see if that helps but NOTHING.

When I've gone into storage it says that I have 810mb in the downloads...so i clicked on it and cleared the two things that I had in there, it's cleared them but is still saying 810mb..

HELP

Answer (score 1):

It might help to get a better look at your internal usage.

An app like [Disk Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1hcS.jpg) has a function to view disk usage. You may be able to use this to identify large files and delete them.

In this particular app, select 'Internal storage' and press the 'Disk map' button to see something like this:

[image: Disk Map]

And you can even long press items in this map to see options to delete them:

[image: Item long-click menu]

Answer (score 0):

Download clean master from Google Play and try to clean your device using this app. Also go into your phone storage section, select miscellaneous and remove all data...

Hope this helps!!